# Removing Alarm From Lock Screen - Galaxy SIII

Tags: lock-screens

I just got an updated replacement phone - a Galaxy S III. I can't figure out how to remove the alarm icon and wake-up time from my lock screen.

I need the alarm set but hate being reminded I have an alarm to go off at 5:30 am every time I look at my phone. And I need the time to show on my lock screen. Just not the dreaded alarm.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK all the android mobiles have this problem. You can not customize it. You should look for Lock Screen replacement in Play Store which is customizable.